# Gear scheme for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I have the following finite difference approximation to the standard 1D heat equation.
$$
\dfrac{3u_j^{n+1} - 4u_j^n + u_j^{n-1}}{2\Delta t}  - \alpha\dfrac{u_{j-1}^{n+1} - 2u_j^{n+1} + u_{j+1}^{n+1}}{\Delta x^2} = 0. 
$$
Then I set
$$
U^n= \begin{pmatrix}u^{n}\\ u^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.
$$ I don'n know how to prove the existence of a matrix $A$ such that
$$
U^{n+1}=AU^n.
$$